# SELECT TOP and SELECT WHERE speed

Tags: sql, sql-server

This will be a simple question to ask:)

Which one is faster (and maybe how much faster)

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id<100000000
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 100000000 * FROM Table ORDER BY Id
```

I assume that Id starts from 1 and increases by 1 so the queries should give the same result.
I have chosen 100 milion records in my example but I really mean "some really big number of records where the speed difference may be noticeable".

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server if that matters.

Comment: What did your measurements show?

Comment: What is the table definition including indexes?

Comment: You do realize that `WHERE Id < 100000000` and `TOP 100000000` are not even the same thing?

Comment: @Tomalak . . . Given the condition that the id's start at 1 and increase incrementally by 1, the two return essentially the same answer (ok, one return 999,999 rows and the other 1,000,000 rows, but that is a quibble).

Comment: @GordonLinoff But that's the only hypothetical condition where it would be true. It would not be true under real-life conditions, where records might be deleted.

Comment: I know it is a controversial thing and I don't have a big exprerience but my approach is "NEVER DELETE ANYTHING FROM DATABASE" :) It may mess up your base or your application in a place where you never expected it like deleting a fired employee makes invoices created by some inexistant guy etc. Use some flag, even overwrite the record with nulls but never delete. So max ID=nr of records is very real-life case for me.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the first is going to be faster.  The first query would scan the table once, do the comparison, and return the rows as it finds them.

The second query would need to sort the `id` column before it can start returning rows.  The sort is more expensive than just reading the table, so that would take longer.

If `id` has an index on it, then the reasoning changes.  The first version might or might not use the index.  If it does, it will scan the index and then fetch the data in the table record by record.

The second query would almost certainly use the index with performance as described in the previous paragraph.  With an index, the two might be equivalent.

Whether using the index is faster than a table scan depends on factors you don't mention -- how large the table is and how much memory you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an estimated query plan for selecting *100 000* rows:

[image: Top Q]

The first plan (49%) uses the ID, and the 2nd plan (51%) uses the `top` clause.  The table structure is not exactly the same, but you get the idea.